# MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: The request could not be completed. (Bad Request) on save images

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am doing a POC application that uses an Android client and a Mobile Azure Service app.

I managed to implement a solution that makes use of a Sql server Compact 4.0 database file in order to store some text and small images (planned maximum 300 Kb for each).

How ever, it only works for really small images (e.g. 2 Kb) that are also compressed in the Jpeg format with the lowest quality

(using this: `image.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 0, stream);`).

I do get "***Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: The request could not be completed.  (Bad Request)***" error for bigger images when trying to save items using the application. I did not find any where in the response any exact mention about request length limit, I assumed this.

So my question would be - **is Azure Storage the only way to accomplish this task ? (also, not sure of any free option using Azure Storage)**.

**UI part with content upload (I am using Xamarin)**

Choose an image to upload (into _currentImage  variable):

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result result, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, result, data);

            if (requestCode == 1)
            {
                if (result == Result.Ok)
                {
                    var selectedImage = data.Data;

                    var filePath = GetPathToImage(selectedImage);

                    var photo = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(filePath);

                    _currentImage = photo;

                    ImagePreview.SetImageBitmap(photo);
                }
            }
        }
```

Save content invoking the Azure Mobile app:

```
private async void UploadItemContent()
        {
            using (MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient(Configuration.Urls.CloudAppUrl))
            {
                var table = client.GetTable<Item>();

                var content = ContentDescriptionEditText.Text;
                var header = ContentHeaderEditText.Text;

                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                _currentImage.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 0, stream);
                var bitmapData = stream.ToArray();

                var item = new Item
                {
                    Content = content,
                    Header = header,
                    Image = bitmapData,
                    CreationDate = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()
                };

                try
                {
                    await table.InsertAsync(item);

                    ShowSuccessStatus();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ShowError(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Backend**

Item definition into the Azure Mobile service:

```
public class Item : ITableData
    {
        public Item()
        {
        }

        [Key]
        [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Id)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Header { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "image")]
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }

        public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        [Index(IsClustered = true)]
        [TableColumn(TableColumnType.CreatedAt)]
        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        [TableColumn(TableColumnType.UpdatedAt)]
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Deleted)]
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }

        [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Version)]
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] Version { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        DateTimeOffset? ITableData.CreatedAt
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        [NotMapped]
        DateTimeOffset? ITableData.UpdatedAt
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
```

ItemController into the Azure Mobile service:

```
public class ItemController : TableController<Item>
    {
        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);

            MobileServiceContext context = new MobileServiceContext();

            DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<Item>(context, Request);
        }

...
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about your code?

Comment: Added related code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Azure Storage for this.   See the recipe in my book here: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter4/recipes/

There is no free option with Azure Storage.